# Haskell List Comp Type Error from Minus in defining range

Tags: haskell, integer, typeerror

Going through older exams, I copied this chunk of code and tried to get it to work.

```
rems :: Integer -> [(Integer ,Integer )]
rems n = [(i, n `mod` i) | i <- [2 ..(n−1)]]
```

Now with the type declaration or without it I get the error:

```
Variable not in scope: (−) :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
ghc version 8.6.3
```

I was able to fix it by doing the calculation of n-1 in a where clause but don't really get why this is a fix. Of course I know what Integer is in Haskell.

```
rems n = [(i, n `mod` i) | i <- [2 ..j] ]
        where j =  n-1
```

Could somebody explain to me why this change of seemingly no effect does fix the error and are there other ways?

Comment: this is strange, because I get a similar error (but with `?` instead of `-`) when I copy-paste your definition, but typing it myself - character-by-character indentical, so it seems - it works fine. I can only assume that you too are copy-pasting and there's some kind of invisible control character there?

Comment: just tried an online diff-checker, it IS highlighting a difference in the final part: `..(n−1)]]`. Still can't see what it is though. Either way, it seems that this isn't really a Haskell question at the end of the day.

Comment: found it, it seems your `-` is actually this: https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2212/index.htm - unicode U+2212, rather than the standard minus sign which is U+002D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a simple typographical error. Your `−` is not a hyphen (which Haskell expects) - it is a Unicode minus-sign character, which is different. Your source must have automatically converted the former to the latter. Just replace it with a hyphen (typed with your keyboard) and it'll work.

Comment: But ... perhaps that *should* be interpreted as a minus sign. That would be a good GHC proposal, methinks.

Comment: @dfeuer You can still do it using `(−) = (-)` (the former is a minus, the latter is a hyphen). It works in GHCi, at least. But the benefit is debatable, in a monospace font.

Comment: The question is whether it should be possible to use minus when declaring a `Num` instance, which would require a modification to the `UnicodeSyntax` language extension. There's no real benefit with a monospaced font, but proportional fonts work fine for Haskell if you format your code in certain ways.

Comment: @dfeuer Yes, that makes more sense.